# IdentityServer4. Access client info from _template

Tags: identityserver4

I want to tweak the page generated based on the "client name".  Can I access the client data from within the ASP _template page, is it available at this point in the pipeline?

I want to have different rendering depending on whether they are using IFrame or not in the first instance. Maybe there is a better way of achieving that

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the user interface in the **AccountController** to be just as you like and it is also in charge of validating the username/password and hence it has full access to the user and client details at that point.

The picture below shows the relationship between IdentityServer and the AccountController class. And the code in the controller is executed before the page is rendered, in classic typical MVC fashion:

[image]

If you want to have multiple layouts, then one option is to have multiple _ViewStart files, as shown in the picture below:
[image]

The alternative depending on how much you need to configure the view, you can always add custom logic inside the layout.cshtml file as well.

Alternatively, you can use the @section feature to include different content into the layout depending on various factors.

You have many options here.

Comment: But the _template page is rendered before the methods in the controller run aren't they?  I want to hide headers and footers when IFRAME client.  Are you saying I should hide them in the controller method?

What is the order of things being called in the pipeline?

Comment: see my updated answer, you can customize that page however you like, you are in control

Comment: I see the methods in account controller fire before the code in _template so perhaps I can pass data in through the model.  In your diagram I want to change the leftmost dialog before the user has logged in.

So that first dialog appears like yours, or it has branding top and bottom if a different client

Comment: Yes, that is how MVC works, the controller runs its logic , chooses what view to execute and then renders the view. Yon can simply verify this by setting a breakpoint in the account controlller class.

Comment: But _template is applied to every page, the model from the controller is passed to the "body" cshtml rendered within the template. I want to alter the template based on the client.  I could put the head/foot in every cshtml and reveal/hide them but the template would be easier.  Obviously every cshtml has its own model, so you can reference it in the template.

I guess the question is can/how do you pass a model to the template page. Alternatively swap out the template page in the controller

Comment: see my updated answer